# Why is this question unclear?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm just intrigued why [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57758/29944) question is unclear. Could you clarify that? Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't vote to close this, but I can see how some users might see it as "unclear".

The following suggestions to improve clarity come from reading *How do I ask a good question?*: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

1. **Be specific**. Note that this question had four questions in the first paragraph, three in the second and three in the third and one in the title. More than one question overloads me as a reader. I would pick one question and focus the title on it.
2. **Search, and research**. Provide some context to focus the question further. One way to do this is with a brief quote or reference. Any reference should be cited (for clarity).  Use the "share" link to get a URL for an SE post used as a reference.  Cite author, title, page number and link, if available, for an outside source. Note that this question had no references.
3. **Make it relevant to others**. Describe the question in such a way as to attract readers so there will be someone to up-vote or answer the question. This is a rhetorical challenge. Choose every word carefully to attract readers. The description of this question seemed unfocused. Perhaps just having fewer words would have improved its clarity and attraction to readers.

These might be some ways to improve the clarity of such a question.